# CheerioJS returns empty results even though the element exists but it works in Python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, request, cheerio

I am trying to do some web scraping for prices and the shipping weight, so I can calculate the shipping costs for my items, I am using Amazon in this case. I tried to use NodeJS and create an API so I can hook it up with a front end for ease of use, but somehow, It doesn't return the element, even though the element clearly exists, and it works in Python as you will see below...

Here's my NodeJS code, for the sake of this question I put the AMD Ryzen's link as a URL:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');

const url = `https://www.amazon.com/AMD-Ryzen-Processor-Wraith-Cooler/dp/B07B428M7F/ref/=sr_1_2/?ie\=UTF8\&qid\=1540883858\&sr\=8-2\&keywords\=amd`;

request(url, (error, response, body) => {
  if(error) console.log(error);
  let $ = cheerio.load(body);
  console.log($('#priceblock_ourprice').text()); // Returns an empty line, even though it works in Python.
});
```

And here's my Python code that works:

```
import requests, urllib, sys
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

d = pq(url="https://www.amazon.com/AMD-Ryzen-Processor-Wraith-Cooler/dp/B07B428M7F/ref/=sr_1_2/?ie\=UTF8\&qid\=1540883858\&sr\=8-2\&keywords\=amd")

print(d('#priceblock_ourprice').text()) # Returns $309.89 as expected.
```

It uses the same URL, but still returns the element as expected, I even tried using different request modules for NodeJS, still the same result, could the problem be with Cheerio? Any inputs are welcome.

Comment: what if you `console.log(body)` ?

Comment: and try console.log(response) also it might be there

Comment: Logging them  to the console works, it returns the entire page, but selecting the item using ID doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got around the problem, I honestly don't know why the span with that id shows in the Python version and not in the NodeJS version, what I did to debug this was dumping the entire response to a file and then search and see if the span with that specific ID was there, and it turned out, it wasn't there... Luckily for me I found a div with attached `data` attributes, and one of those data attributes was the price, so I changed my DOM selector to:

```
$('#cerberus-data-metrics').data('asin-price')
```

And it works now.

Comment: This doesn't surprise me, you can expect Amazon to send different responses based on things like headers, cookies, geography, etc.

Comment: @pguardiario Yes it does, but at some point it should be constant or at least sync up with either versions, I still don't understand why the Python version worked and not the NodeJS one.

Comment: Amazon is giving you 2 different versions of that page because your headers are different.

Comment: @pguardiario Any ideas on how can I send the same headers?

Comment: Yes you can check the headers at httpbin.org/headers and go to requests github page  for documentation on setting those. I would use axios if it were me.